# Hide highway numbers without removing the directions

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to style the map which shows the directions of all roads without the road numbers on them.

```
{
    featureType: "road.highway",
    elementType: "labels.icon",
    stylers: [
        {color:"#979897"},
    { lightness: 50 },
    { visibility: "off" }
    ]
},
```

But this removes the directions on the road as well the numbers.I want to show only the directions without the highway numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "this removes the directions on the road"?  Are you using the [directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) for directions?  Or are you asking about something that is part of the map tiles?

Comment: I meant by the traffic direction on the roads using arrows

Answer (score 6):

This code removes all icons as well as labels.  I am not sure what you mean by directional arrows, is this an additional layer you have?

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I meant the small arrows on the roads which indicate the direction of the traffic on it.

Comment: This also turns off street names. Is there any way to keep street names but turn off road numbers?

Comment: I also want to remove street numbers and keep street names

Answer (score 2):

There's a very useful styling tool which allows you to visually tweak map settings, which then spits out the JSON you need for your settings:

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Jeremy's answer will remove labels from all roads, including highways, arterial roads and local roads. I suspect you only want to hide highway numbers, so use:

```
        [
          {
              "featureType": "road.highway",
              "elementType": "labels",
              "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
              ]
          }
        ]
```

(This will also hide highway labels though).

You can also remove labels for arterial and local roads separately, if desired, by adding additional JSON objects using the following as the "featureType":

- road.arterial
- road.local